# How to make multiple dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently learned javascript and I wanted to make a dropdown menu. So with a hand from google, I succeeded. The problem is that when I want to create multiple of these dropdowns it doesn't work the way I want. The dropdowns remain open even after I click outside the section. I have tried doing many things with this, which I am not going to show because it is a bit confusing and my last question got deleted. Here is my code.

index.html

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <a onclick="myFunction()" class="nav-link dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
        <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
    <a onclick="myFunction()" class="nav-link dropbtn">Dropdown2</a>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
        <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

script.js

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}


window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and style.css

```css
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #3b86ff;
    z-index: 1;
    min-width: 150px;

}

.dropdown-content a {
    padding: 14px 16px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}


.show {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is in the code. You were very close. This may look alot different but it's small differences. The click listeners are better off in your script rather than in the elements. Take a look and ask any questions you might have

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // wait until the page loads before working with HTML elements
  document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    //click listener on the document
    document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content').forEach(function(el) {
      if (el !== event.target) el.classList.remove('show')
      // close any showing dropdown that isn't the one just clicked
    });
    if (event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
      event.target.closest('.dropdown').querySelector('.dropdown-content').classList.toggle('show')
    }
    // if this is a dropdown button being clicked, toggle the show class
  })
})
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3b86ff;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 150px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href='#' class="nav-link dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
    <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
    <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
  <a href='#' class="nav-link dropbtn">Dropdown2</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
    <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
    <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks man, i will implement this in my code, but i do find it a little hard to understand, maybe because i am new to javascript

Comment: also what is el

Comment: iterating functions like `forEach` automatically create at last one argument, which is the current element of the iteration. You can call that anything, it's just a variable. I call it `el`.  So `document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content').forEach(function(el)` is looping (iterating) through each instance of an element with the class `.dropdown-content` and in each loop we can access the element with `el`